# Sick leopard gecko

Tags: behavior, reptiles, leopard-geckos

I have had my leo since February. His name is Elvis (I think it's a male). The last two weeks he has been very lethargic and slowly not eating, and now more recently he's not pooping. It started when he was having trouble shedding. I waited a few days before I helped him. I had to soak him in warm water and use a Q-Tip. I have entirely cleaned out his cage, giving fresh crickets and mealworms. But still nothing. As of right now he hasn't pooped in about 4+ days. He barely moves, and when he does, it's slowly. He doesn't even do much when I open his cage and touch him. He is starting to lose weight and I am very worried about him.

Answer (score 3):

I would go to the vet hospital if he's constipated for 4+ days and not eating/lethargic for 2 weeks.

A veterinarian will have to do a physical exam to determine cause.